# How long does a PDO connection stay open for

Tags: php, pdo

I have removed a lot of code, but the basic structure is like so

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".$config::DB_HOST.";dbname=".$config::DB_NAME."", $config::DB_USER, $config::DB_PASSWORD);
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO ...(...) VALUES (...)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $inputArray[0]);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $inputArray[1]);

if($stmt->execute()) {
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        foreach($_FILES as $file) {
            ...
        }
        if(!$upload->get_errors()) {
            $pdf = new PDF\PdfGenerator($fileData, $inputArray);

            if($pdf) {
                //zip file

                if ($sevenZipArchive->compress()) {
                    //Mail file

                    if(!$mail->send()) {

                    } else {
                        $pdfs = glob('/pdfs/*');
                        foreach($pdfs as $pdf){
                            if(is_file($pdf)) {
                                unlink($pdf);
                            }
                        }

                        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE ...  SET col5 = ?");
                        $stmt->bindParam(1, $inputArray[0]);

                        $data['success'] = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    $errors['result'] = '- Compression Failed';
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $errors['file'] = '- ...';
    }
} else {
    $errors['result'] = '- ...';
}
```

So I first insert data into my database.  I then do a load of other stuff, until finally I need to update the initial insert to set a column with a new value.

My main question is whether the initial PDO connection would still be available when it comes time to UPDATE.  Also, I dont think the UPDATE is working the way I am doing it.  What would be the best way to update the initial insert?

Thanks